# Error XPST0003 in QML

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I'm trying to parse the result of xmlrpc call to wordpress into xmllistmodel. The model is here:

```
XmlListModel {
        id: dataModel
        query: "/methodResponse/params/param/value/array/data/value/"
        XmlRole {name: "postId"; query:"struct/member[1]/value/int/number()"; isKey: true}
        XmlRole {name: "title"; query: "struct/member[6]/value/string()"}
}
```

and here is the xml data:

```
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <array>
                    <data>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member><name>ID</name><value><int>358</int></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_author</name><value><string>3</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_date</name><value><string>2008-09-05 00:27:25</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_date_gmt</name><value><string>2008-09-05 07:27:25</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_content</name><value><string>Some content</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_title</name><value><string>Readability Test</string></value></member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member><name>ID</name><value><int>188</int></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_author</name><value><string>3</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_date</name><value><string>2008-09-04 23:02:20</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_date_gmt</name><value><string>2008-09-05 06:02:20</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_content</name><value><string>Some content</string></value></member>
                                <member><name>post_title</name><value><string>Layout Test</string></value></member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </data>
                </array>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

So what is the problem, and what causes these errors:

```
Error XPST0003 in file:///usr/bin/qmlviewer, at line 1, column 62: syntax error, unexpected end of file
Error XPST0003 in file:///usr/bin/qmlviewer, at line 2, column 40: syntax error, unexpected )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know WordPress but it might be complaining because this:

```
query: "/methodResponse/params/param/value/array/data/value/"
```

is not a valid XPath expression. There should be no trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've forgot about that trailing slash after playing with many other things in the qml file.